# How to write a @POST request correctly?

Tags: android, post, retrofit, retrofit2

I trying to make an `@POST` request. When I make this request

```
 @POST("/testAPI")
    @Headers("token: rAhUCUo-wz-Sbtwjt1")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<GetEntires> getEntires(@Field("a")String method,
                                @Field("session")String SessionId);
```

I get in response: HTML code of site API, but when I make a request in a special program (is Chrome app - ARC) I get the right response, which equals response from documentation of API.
Example of request from documentation of API:

```
curl --header "token: EXAMPLETOKEN" --data "a=new_session" https://bnet.i-partner.ru/testAPI/
```

Where I made mistake or whatever?

[image]

**UPDATE:**
How look request in text from app ARC:

```
POST /testAPI/ HTTP/1.1
HOST: bnet.i-partner.ru
token: rAhUCUo-wz-Sbtwjt1
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryLA3TDEc7BbGOFNMS
content-length: 256

------WebKitFormBoundaryLA3TDEc7BbGOFNMS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="a"

get_entries
------WebKitFormBoundaryLA3TDEc7BbGOFNMS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="session "

tThEPaP7uvGWje176p
------WebKitFormBoundaryLA3TDEc7BbGOFNMS--
```

And response from server:

```
{
"status": 1,
"data": [
  [],
],
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you add the `"Content-Type: multipart/form-data"` header to retrofit like you did in ARC? I'm not sure it adds by default

Comment: In the update of question, i show how look  request  and response in text, with type `multipart/form-data` it work

Comment: So it was just missing the content type?

Comment: yep, thank you. I just added `@Multipart` , and use `@Part`, and all works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me, it works:

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/testAPI")
    fun createPost(@Part("a") post: String?,
                   @Part("session") post2: String?): Call<Post?>?
```

I used `@Part`